# Jump in a list of IPs in a foreach

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a little script to gather some wisdom and options in one script. For later and for myself. It's a simple one but with lot of informations and "reusability".

I'm now trying to achive a jump in an "running" process of a list. All I could think of till now is to achive this via regex. But I can barley use regex properly.

```
#Custom Ping to identify the scenario
function Custom-Ping {
    Param(
        [string]$Address
    )
    $ping = ping $Address /w 1 /n 1
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*(100% loss)*")) {
        $result = "Error"
    } elseif(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ping -Like "*expired*")) {
        $result = "Warning"
    } else {
        $result = "succeded"
    }
    return $result
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$tstart = Get-Date
$counter = 0
$unreachable = 0

$IPlist = foreach ($Network in 1..29) {
    foreach ($Range in 1..254) {
        "10.10.$Network.$Range"
    }
}

foreach ($IP in $IPlist) {
    $counter ++
    try {
        if ($unreachable -lt 6) {
            #SwitchCase
            $case = Custom-Ping $IP

            switch ($case) {
                succeded {
                    Write-Host "Response from: $IP" -ForegroundColor Green
                    #$IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                }
                Error {
                    Write-Host "No Response from: $IP" -ForegroundColor Red
                    #$IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                }
                Warning {
                    Write-Host "Time Expired on: $IP" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    #$IP | Export-CSV -path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                    $unreachable ++
                }
                default {
                    Write-Warning "An Error Occured while processing"
                }
            }
        } else {
            #Hop to the next range as this range isnt accesibble
            #$IPswap = $IP
            #newIP = $Ipswap "$Network from 2 to 3"
            #$IP=$newIP
            $unreachable = 0
            Write-Host "The Network xxxx cant be reached"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Other Error"
    }
}

$tend = Get-Date
Write-Host "$counter Completed Ping requests"
New-TimeSpan -Start $tstart -End $tend | select Minutes, Seconds
```

This is the script so far... I didn't find a way till now to achive this jump of the "network".

For Example it got 5 unreachable in 10.10.2.0 network and then sets to 10.10.3.0 network and starts there again with the process.

I was wondering if this is even possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops and labels instead:

```
:Network # Now we can jump into the next iteration of this loop from an inner loop
foreach ($Network in 0..29)
{
    :Host
    foreach($Node in 0..254){
        $IP = "10.10.$Network.$Node"

        #Counter for "Statistic"
        $counter ++
        try
        {
            #Check error sum for Range Hop
            if($unreachable -lt 6)
            {
                #SwitchCase
                $case = Custom-Ping $IP

                switch ($case)
                {
                succeded
                {           
                    Write-Host "Response from: $IP" -ForegroundColor Green
                    #$IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                }
                Error
                {     
                    Write-Host "No Response from: $IP" -ForegroundColor Red
                    #$IP | Export-Csv -Path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                }
                Warning
                {
                    Write-Host "Time Expired on: $IP" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    #$IP | Export-CSV -path D:\somepath.csv -Append
                    $unreachable ++
                }
                default
                {
                    Write-Warning "An Error Occured while processing"
                }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $unreachable = 0
                Write-Host "The Network 10.10.$Network.0/24 cant be reached, jumping to 10.10.$($Network + 1).0/24"

                # jump forward to the next iteration of the outer "Network" loop
                continue Network
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning "Other Error" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok I guess I get the hang out of it, just for clearification; the `:Network` and `:Host` is kind of a "stack pointer" am I wrong with this?

Comment: Not really, but that is a useful way of interpreting it - control flow statements like `break` and `continue` can now say "unwind to X" rather than "unwind to last".

Comment: I see well thank you for your information and help :), this helps alot